# Gem Carrierwave is not allowing application/octet-stream file to upload

Tags: carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-2.4

using Rails 5.2, ruby 2.4 gem carrierwave

```
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
```

when I upload with extension mdl and content type: application/octet-stream 
It return on file save  the following error

```
    ["Job data file You are not allowed to upload \"mdl\" files, 
allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png, application/octet-stream"]
```

But I have included the content type: application/octet-stream as showing in the error.
My Uploader file is as:

```
class JobDataFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png application/octet-stream)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

updated the uploader file of filed with

```
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(mdl)
  end
```

I thourgh will take the content type same a paperclip do for validation like "application/octet-stream".